# Is there a master list of COMExceptions?

Tags: .net, exception, com

The Oracle community has a several support sites ([here](http://www.11ghelp.com/map/sitemap-110.html) and [here](http://www.oracleabc.com/oracledocs/11gErrors/)) that have lists of errors.  The first site even has suggestions for how to fix them.

Does anyone know of an equivalent list for Microsoft COM, preferably with Office Interop issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, every component is permitted to define its own.  The only restrictions are that error values must have the high bit set, and the bits in the middle are *supposed* to identify the component.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) has an article showing how the bits of the error code are divided up.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705941(VS.85).aspx) is ms's general com ex list; pretty short but its something. When I was working with OWC, I typically found them scattered on different sites or in separate blog entries. (Yay Google)